# Complex Analysis - Defining a branch cut for a function with multiple branches which DON'T lie on an axis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

For the function:
$$f(z)=(z+\sqrt{3})^{1/2}\ln{(z-1)}$$
with the branch of this function chosen such that
$$-\frac{4\pi}{3}<\arg{(z-1)}\leq\frac{2\pi}{3}$$ and $$-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg{(z+\sqrt{3})}\leq\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
How would I find a single branch definition for this function? I am used to the method when both branch cuts lie on the $x$ or $y$ axis by analyzing the regions on the axis by showing if the function is the same above and below the axis and therefore whether a branch cut is required in this region. I am completely lost on what to do for this question since one of the branch cuts is not even parallel to an axis.

Comment: Introduce factors that rotate the branch cuts:
$$f(z) = e^{\pi i/4} \sqrt {-i (z + \sqrt 3)} \left(
 \ln(e^{\pi i/3} (z - 1)) - \frac {\pi i} 3 \right),$$
where $\sqrt z$ and $\ln z$ denote the principal value. This is the same analytic function on $\mathbb C \setminus ([1, 1 + e^{2 \pi i/3} \infty) \cup [-\sqrt 3, -\sqrt 3 - i \infty))$.